# CPTTestApp-ipad example in CorePlot_0.9

Tags: ipad, core-plot, sigabrt

I am very new to core plot. I saw different examples in CorePlot_0.9. I tried to run, but its  show errors related to shells. Then I create a new project and copy the code.Then it build successfully, but it shows the error Thread 1:Program received signal:"SIGABRT" in scatterPlotView.hostedGraph = graph;`Unknown class CPTGraphHostingView in Interface Builder file.
2012-02-21 09:16:30.336 coreplttest[285:b303] -[UIView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x686e500
2012-02-21 09:16:30.686 coreplttest[285:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x686e500'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fb65a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0110a313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00fb80bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f27966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00f27522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   coreplttest                         0x00002dd8 -[coreplttestViewController constructScatterPlot] + 360
    6   coreplttest                         0x00002c13 -[coreplttestViewController viewDidLoad] + 99
    7   UIKit                               0x002b8089 -[UIViewController view] + 179
    8   UIKit                               0x0022bd42 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 51
    9   coreplttest                         0x000028d7 -[coreplttestAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 135
    10  UIKit                               0x00208c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
    11  UIKit                               0x0020ad88 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 439
    12  UIKit                               0x00215617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    13  UIKit                               0x0020dabf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    14  UIKit                               0x00212f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x01afe992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00f97944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00ef7cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00ef4f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00ef4840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00ef4761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    21  UIKit                               0x0020a7d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623
    22  UIKit                               0x00216c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    23  coreplttest                         0x00002819 main + 121
    24  coreplttest                         0x00002795 start + 53
)
terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)` What is the error ? I tried again and again to fix, but I can't.Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

This message is the key: "-[UIView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector". It means the view that you want to use as your hosting view is set up as a `UIView`, not as a `CPTGraphHostingView`. Make sure you set the custom class correctly in Interface Builder.

Comment: I checked it and it is CPTGraphHostingView its self.